# What does "the least possible value" mean?

Tags: ambiguity, modifiers, superlatives

I was working on a GMAT question:

> The **least possible value** for the mean of the numbers of hours of TV reported for the week is [choices].

It a single choice question. But in the phrase "the least possible value" which word does `least` modify? `possible` or `value`?

If it modifies `possible`, it means the value that is the most impossible. If it modifies `value`, it means the least value among all possible ones. Which one does the phrase actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it doesn't make sense that you could modify the word *possible* with *least* (or *most*).

Something either *is* possible or it *isn't*.

Colloquially, people do sometimes make this mistake. But what they are really trying to express is the idea of something that is the least or most *probable* or *likely*.

You *can* say *the least number of possibilities*—but that's something different.

So, I would assume that *least* is modifying *value* in the GMAT question because it doesn't make sense for it to be modifying *possible*.

Answer (score 1):

**least** is a superlative and thus is predicated against *a set of things or possibilities*.

You are being asked to identify the least (of) {the possible values}.

So it's {least}{possible value}.

BTW, an impossible value is not a "least possible" value.  The least possible percentage of oxygen in the air that is needed for us to remain conscious is not zero percent oxygen.